# Can a cookie expire when EITHER some time passes OR browser is closed?

Tags: http, cookies, browser, session-cookies

I know that I can set expiration date for a cookie, but can I make a cookie expire after some time OR when browser is closed?

Comment: Maybe see also answers of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894243/why-cookies-dont-expire-after-closing-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894243/why-cookies-dont-expire-after-closing-browser) and [Wikipedia: HTTP cookie - Expires and Max-Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age). There are two cases of Cookies depending on whether Expires is set or not. If set, make a cookie expire after some time, or expire when browser is closed if not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you set an expiration date, this will set them to expire on that date, whether the browser is open or closed.

Only non persisted cookies will expire once the browser is closed.

See [cookie expiration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expiration) rules on wikipedia.

Comment: I knew about that. I just came with idea to send multiple cookies one with expiration date and other which expire with user session. Checking both will give me desired result

Comment: I actually implemented it the same way as @SergejAndrejev where I used two cookies.

Comment: @SergejAndrejev, you should convert your comment to answer

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the use case? Different things that should expire at different times?

Comment: It was a bank front-end. The user should be logged out when he either closes the browser or after some amount of minutes. If I remember correctly, that was quite some time ago

Comment: @SergejAndrejev do you remember what you did you solve it in the end?

Comment: was long time and a different carreer ago, but I think I used non-persistant cookies and javascript to close web page once the user logs out