# Keep a user logged in using cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have the following code to login:

```
$query_login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE
  username='".mysql_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' AND
  password='".mysql_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'");

if(mysql_num_rows($query_login)) { 
  $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['username'];
  header('Location:account.php');
}
```

This is only valid for the life of a session. When a user closes his/her browser the session is gone and the user needs to login again.

How do I securely persist sessions using cookies?

I'm concerned that inserting usernames and passwords into cookies is unsafe.

Comment: You must save the cookie in the cookie jar, and set the TTL (Time To Live) to something large. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894243/why-cookies-dont-expire-after-closing-browser

Comment: On the link I just suggested this is a duplicate of, proceed beyond the accepted answer to the much better answer below it by 
ircmaxell

Answer (score -1):

If the user has a user id in the database then you can store it in a cookie

Edit:

Here is code: (this is from my phone so sorry for the presentation)

```
$query_login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE
  username='".mysql_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' AND
 password='".mysql_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'");

$result = mysql_query($query_login);

$user = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    setcookie('login', $user['user_id'], time() + (60*60*24*1000);
    header('Location:account.php');
}
```

Comment: Can you show him how to implement this with some piece of code?