# cookie expiry time not set to destroy after each browser close but it is not working

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I am setting a cookie at first, when I close the browser the cookie is supposed to be destroyed so I am not setting any expiry time. But somehow the cookie is not getting destroyed even after closing the browser.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_COOKIE['favcolor']))
{
   echo $_COOKIE['favcolor'];
}
else
{
   $_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
   setcookie('favcolor', 'green',0);
   echo 'new cookie and session are set';
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you closing only the tab or the full browser?

Comment: full browser @lbu

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing this in? I couldn't replicate the issue locally in Sarari and Chrome - these both acted as expected - but I could in Firefox.

Comment: Check the browser console. Look at what is the current expiration date set when you set the cookie

Comment: i am using crome @Enright

Comment: welli dont know how to do that @lbu. i will google it and let you know Thanks buddy :)

Comment: favcolor green localhost /testzone 1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z - this is what i got from crome console about my cookie

Comment: i tried to access the same file in edge and it worked fine i guess there is some problem with my browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your code appears to be correct as presented. As stated in the PHP docs for [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).

This is known as a "session cookie" and should be deleted by the browser when it closes.

Looking into this a little, it appears that Chrome and Firefox behave a little differently depending if they are configured to remember open tabs and windows at startup, and this is by design.

You mentioned you are using Chrome - if Chrome is configured to "Continue where you left off" at startup, session cookies might not be deleted when the tab closed and browser is restarted.

[image]

I can verify that the cookie is deleted when the browser is closed when I choose "Open the New Tab page".

This is the same with Firefox - there is some additional information with some details about how you can [configure this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/970539) on the Mozilla support forum.

In short, it appears that you might not be able to rely on the Chrome or Firefox to guarantee deleting a session cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Enright .It is spot on and clearly explains why cookies are behaving this way.Thanks for your effort and time.

Comment: My pleasure :) I definitely learned something from your question, so thanks to you too!