# How to keep authentication token?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, session-storage

The React website has following requirements:

1. Stay logged in when opening a page of the current website in new tab.
2. Log out if browser is closed and reopened.
3. Stay logged in on page refresh.
4. IE11 support :(.

If I keep auth token in sessionStorage, it meets the 2 requirement but not the 1.
If I use localStorage - 1 but not 2.

If I use:

```
window.onunload = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem('authtoken');
};
```

it meets 1 and 2 conditions but it also clears storage when I refresh the page which shouldn't happen too!

This solution to check if the page is refreshing can't be used in IE11
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53307588/12994741

So how should I keep the auth token? Any way to make it? Maybe it's possible to prevent unload event on refreshing in React?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [session cookies](https://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/session-cookies-used-for.html).

1. It keeps its value when you open a same website in different tabs.
2. They are expired once the browser exits.
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/8894280/15881471
3. It keeps its value on page refresh.
4. It works for IE11, though there are some caveats.
   https://github.com/cmp-cc/vue-cookies/issues/29